# Typescript - Advantages of Setters/Getters?

Tags: javascript, typescript, setter, getter

I am a backend developer that has developed mostly in Java so I was taught to use setters/getters instead of directly accessing the properties of a class.

Now I'm getting into the frontend world and now got to js/ts. I've seen lot of people access object variables directly without setters and getters as you'd do in Java such as `this.person.name`.

Why is this? Is there any advantage on using getter/setter on ts and js if you don't need to add extra code but just to get the value or set it?

Thanks.

Comment: Personal opinion:  I think the big difference between the two languages is the mentality.  Java, as you probably know, is totally obsessive-compulsive about "the right way" to do things, often flat out forcing you into doing it that way.

Javascript tends to be more of a shoot-from-the-hip cowboy language.  Just get in and make it work.

Also, JavaScript seems more disposable where Java is more long-term maintainable.

(Again, these are more observations than measurable facts.)

Answer (score 10):

A difference between using a getter or setter and accessing object variables directly is that getters/setters are automatically invoked on assignment. So it looks just like a normal property but behind the scenes you can have extra logic (or checks) to be run just before or after the assignment.

So if you decide to add this kind of extra logic to one of the existing object properties already has references, you can convert it to getter/setter style without altering the rest of the code that has access to that property.

```
let person = {
    _age: 50,

    set age(newage){
      if(typeof newage === 'number'){
           this._age = newage;
            console.log('valid input')
      }
      else{
           console.log ('Invalid input');
      }
    }

  };
```

Comment: so the only advantage is adding more code into the function? nothing about security or other?

Comment: You can't use 'public' and 'private' keywords in javascript, but you can use local variables if you want private properties for example

Comment: @Wrong Pros: 1. Encapsulation 2. Flexibility; Cons: Performance. Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

@Pointy is wrong to say: *it's really a good idea to forget everything about Java when learning JavaScript*. Encapsulation is an object oriented principle of hiding the internal state and behaviour of an object, making your code more maintainable.

In javascript you make tings work with no/messy structure. Typescript is a superset of javascript, this guy is your friend if you are a C#, Java or any other object oriented language  programmer.

Example:
in myobject.**Ts**

```
export class MyObject {

   // private property
   private _x: number;
   private _z: number;

   // public property
   y: number;

   constructor(private _d?: number) {
       this._x = 0;
       this.y = 0;
       this._z = 0;

       this.clog(_d)
   }

   // access modifier only for _x
   get x() {
       return this._x;
   }
   set x(value: number) {
       this._x = value;
   }

   private clog(d: number) { 
       console.log(d);
   }

   // arrow function -> public
   testf = () => { console.log('value of this._d' , this._d); }
}
```

then you get in myobject.**js** this:

```
export class MyObject {
   constructor(_d) {
       this._d = _d;
       // arrow function -> public
       this.testf = () => { console.log('value of this._d', this._d); };
       this._x = 0;
       this.y = 0;
       this.clog(_d);
   }
   // access modifier
   get x() {
       return this._x;
   }
   set x(value) {
       this._x = value;
   }
   clog(d) {
       console.log(d);
   }
}
```

Let's use it in main.**Ts**:

```
import { MyObject } from './myobject';

let mo = new MyObject(15);

// set a value to the private property x
mo.x = 5;

// get the value of the private property x
// output 5
console.log(mo.x);
```

vscode and intellisense:
[image]

with intellisense in vscode you see that it does not show the private property _z and the private function clog().

I suggest you to watch this tutorial and make a better idea. [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NjN00cM18Z4)

Comment: But you have encapsulated nothing, really.

Comment: This doesnt make any sense at all, the point of encapsulation is maintainability, which in case of getters and setters is achieved by the redefining the "syntax" to access attribute/property.

What you did is encapsulation without actual encapsulation, because syntax is the same as if it was direct access.

This would only be usefull if getter doesnt just return value of attribute but the result certain of operation.

Answer (score 0):

BIG difference.  Accessing the instance attribute directly means you are strongly coupling your dependent class directly to the source class' attribute.

Whenever you change that attribute to a different type or maybe initialize it in a format that's not expected of the dependent class, you will then need to re-compile this dependent class again.

Is it bad? It depends.  The purpose of encapsulation is not security and all that stuff, people say a ton of things without understanding what was really the reason for encapsulation.  It's for managing the maintenance profile of your source code by reducing "spaghettification" of pointers.

If you encapsulate the attribute to only be accessible through a method/function, then you decrease the coupling of those two classes because the pointer points to the interface (another name for a function) and not directly to the memory allocation of the attribute.  So if you change the memory allocation, you don't end up changing runtime values or recompiling all the classes that point to that allocation.  The latter seems not a big deal since we all have crazy fast computers and compilers nowadays, but the former can be a headache to maintain.

With regards to languages, JavaScript started out as a scripting language and not as a bonafide programming language that compiles to an executable. This is one of the reasons why it's mostly okay to access the attributes directly - especially with vanilla JavaScript. It has more freedom and it's not strictly-typed.  Developers can do whatever they want with it - as long as they know what they're doing and what they're getting into. That is why there are so many frameworks for JavaScript, each of them enforcing their programming mechanisms differently, some enforce a more object oriented mechanism while others don't.

Java is a strictly-typed full blown compilable programming language, a bit more newbie proof because of explicit rules that can serve as guide.  That's why frameworks for Java are mostly limited to boiler plating and dependency injection, and they are easier to grasp because you don't have to learn new mechanisms to understand what's going on.

Comment: If you started off with a property, but decided you need a getter it's *rarely* an issue because in most real-world scenarios people control both caller and callee. Setters-by-default is a great example of a premature optimization that adds cognitive overhead, *unless* the API is shipped to other parties and BC has to be maintained. In Javascript this is not even a concern because properties can overriden later to be dynamic with get. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

Comment: @Evert, yeah which is why I said in JavaScript it's mostly okay.

Comment: It's premature optimization in most of Java too. I understand it may be idiomatic but it doesn't make it a good idea. Just like FactoryFactories.

Comment: @Evert, No it's not.  I've been practicing software engineering in Java for more than 2 decades and this is not even something we debate about in backend development.  Try that in astute companies with big teams and watch your MRs get rejected.  That's just bad practice and will severely impact the maintenance characteristics of your codebase and impact your build and test times once the app becomes a monster.  You can get away with 1 or 2 dependencies like that because you own the callee and caller, but wait till you get 10 classes depending on that single callee variable directly.

Comment: I don't feel I need to share my credentials and experience, but I agree with you on one point: MRs will get rejected.

Comment: I'm not trying to be against you, since you're an accomplished professional yourself, but I highly disagree with "in most of Java too" part of your comment.  Like I said, I worked in Java for a long time since v1.4, and that's not something I witness and see Java pros like me do, and for a very good reason "in most of Java".  Even NASA and the army bans this practice of directly accessing variables for Java for the reasons I mentioned.  Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm aware I'm being controversial and going against the established norms in typical Java shops. You're not wrong, I just have a different opinion. I believe there's nothing inherit to 'java the language' that requires this more than other languages, but it's become the established way of doing things for quite a while.

Comment: no worries, thanks for your contribution in this conversation!

Comment: Answer should be minimum lines with clear understandings.

Comment: @sandipbharadva I don't think it's hard to understand String name = myObject.getName() vs. String name = myObject.name.